# I want to erase the circle once it is clicked on. However, whenever I click it nothing happens

Tags: java

So this is the class where I create the circles which works fine.

```
public class CircleAnimations {

    private ArrayList<Circle> circles; // the circles to animate
    private int size; // canvas width and height (will be square)
    private Random rng; // use to make random numbers

    /** create a drawing pane of a particular size */
    public CircleAnimations(int s) {
        circles = new ArrayList<>();
        size = s;
        rng = new Random();

//don't mess with this
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(size, size); // set up drawing canvas
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, size); // <0, 0> is bottom left. <size-1, size-1> is top right
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, size);
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
            circles.get(i).draw();
        }
    }

    public void addCircle() {
        circles.add(new Circle(rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(75),
                new Color(rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255))));
        circles.add(new Circle(rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(75),
                new Color(rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255))));
        circles.add(new Circle(rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(size - 1), rng.nextInt(75),
                new Color(rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255), rng.nextInt(255))));
        drawCircle();
    }

    public void removeClicked() {
        addCircle();
        while (circles.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = circles.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                double mouseXPos = StdDraw.mouseX();
                double mouseYPos = StdDraw.mouseY();
                if (StdDraw.isMousePressed()) {
                    if (mouseXPos < circles.get(i).getX() + circles.get(i).getRadius()
                            || mouseXPos > circles.get(i).getX() - circles.get(i).getRadius()) {
                        if (mouseYPos < circles.get(i).getY() + circles.get(i).getRadius()
                                || mouseYPos > circles.get(i).getX() - circles.get(i).getRadius()) {
                            circles.remove(i);
                            drawCircle();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

The method for deleting the circle which was clicked on isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Is throwing an Exception? Like ConcurrentModificationException, or what error do you have?

Comment: It's probably an algorithm error since the code compiles and runs fine, just that when I click on a circle it doesn't become removed.

Comment: If you are using a library or framework for drawing graphics kindly tag it if a tag exists.

Comment: I believe I'm using this class written by my teacher https://github.com/asdfasdfasd669/Circles/blob/main/StdDraw.java

Comment: Ok so you cant tag it but you may want to add that in the question itself.

Comment: Where are you calling `removeClicked`? Have you tied it to `MouseEvent`s somehow? Otherwise, your program won’t ever know that that should be called.

Comment: https://github.com/asdfasdfasd669/Circles/blob/main/CircleRunner.java I'm calling the method in this CircleRunner class